Display images in using mapping in React
I am creating a simple movie website using React, the details such as name, genre, description e.t.c all are displayed except for the movie image which is provides in the movie_data.js file. How do I solve this and what could be the issue?
movie_data.js file:
export default [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Oppenheimer",
        image:"../images/opennheimer.jpg",
        description: "The story of J. Robert Oppenheimer’s role in the development of the atomic bomb during World War II.",
        Genre: "Biography, Drama, History",
        Actor: "Cillian Murphy, Emily Blunt, Robert Downey Jr",
        Director: "Christopher Nolan",
        Country: "United States, United Kingdom"
    }
]

movie_component.js file:
function MovieComponent(prop)
{
    return (
        <div className="movie-container">
            <img src={prop.items.image} alt={prop.items.name}/>
            <h2>{prop.items.name}</h2>
            <p>{prop.items.description}</p>
            <p>{prop.items.Genre}</p>
            <p>{prop.items.Actor}</p>
            <p>{prop.items.Director}</p>
            <p>{prop.items.Country}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

movie_app.js file:
function MovieApp()
{
    const movieElements = movie_data.map(function(dataItems){
        return <MovieComponent id={dataItems.id} items={dataItems}/>
    })
    return (movieElements)
}

I expected the images for each movie to be displayed, however I only get text details.

There is a possibility that the file path of the image property is not pointing to the actual directory where the images are saved. You need to inspect that and point the images to the right directory.

I checked  and ensured that the file location is working. Does it have to do with importing  images in react ``import myImage from "file_location" and passing it as javascript object in your component

I think your path is not resolving correctly. You can get this solved in two ways:

Import your image into the component or the file where the movies dataset is imported from:

import opennheimerImg from "../images/opennheimer.jpg"

export const movies = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Oppenheimer",
        image: opennheimerImg,
        description: "The story of J. Robert Oppenheimer’s role in the development of the atomic bomb during World War II.",
        Genre: "Biography, Drama, History",
        Actor: "Cillian Murphy, Emily Blunt, Robert Downey Jr",
        Director: "Christopher Nolan",
        Country: "United States, United Kingdom"
    }
]


You can move your images folder into the public folder and reference it from the root.

export const movies = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Oppenheimer",
        image: "/images/opennheimer.jpg",
        description: "The story of J. Robert Oppenheimer’s role in the development of the atomic bomb during World War II.",
        Genre: "Biography, Drama, History",
        Actor: "Cillian Murphy, Emily Blunt, Robert Downey Jr",
        Director: "Christopher Nolan",
        Country: "United States, United Kingdom"
    }
]

I'm sure both of these solutions would work for your use-case.

You can solve this issue using ES5 require property like below. but make sure to set the correct path of image relative to your component directory.
function MovieComponent(prop) {
    return (
        <div className="movie-container">
            <img src={require(prop.items.image)} alt={prop.items.name}/>
            <h2>{prop.items.name}</h2>
            <p>{prop.items.description}</p>
            <p>{prop.items.Genre}</p>
            <p>{prop.items.Actor}</p>
            <p>{prop.items.Director}</p>
            <p>{prop.items.Country}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

